# How can I make a container fill the entire window?

Tags: html, css

I have a main container in CSS that contains all divs for the page.  However, there is a white space of 8px pushing the entire container to the left.  Any idea how I can get rid of it, and have the container fit the entire window without white space?  If I use "margin-left: -8px" it just creates 8 pixels of white space on the right.  Heres the code for the container:

```
#container {
height: 100%;
width: auto;
position: relative;
background-color: #E6E6E6;
min-width: 960px;
}
```

Comment: The `body` has a default margin of `8px`... simply set `body{margin:0px}`..

Answer (score 2):

Just set `margin: 0px;` on `#container`, if that does not work you can set

```
body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the default styles being applied by the browser stylesheet.

---

There are a few ways you can solve you're problem:

Apply this css rule, which effectively get's rid of any default padding or margin applied to elements.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Or you could use a css reset stylesheet, which I recommend the most because different browsers handle elements somewhat differently and you want to even the field out so you don't run into any problems later. I recommend Eric Mayers css reset stylesheet it can be found here: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ and I use it for my own projects.

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body, #container {margin:0; min-height:100%;}
```